# Error during chef verify

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I installed the chef client and chefdk on Linux. Also downloaded the chef repo.

When I try

chef verify, I get the following error. Please help.

```
/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/ruby: /lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.6' not found ( required by /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/lib ruby.so.2.1)

/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/ruby: /lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.9' not found ( required by   /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/lib ruby.so.2.1)
```

Also knife client list on the chef-repo also returns the same error. What is wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 4):

You are installing the wrong package for your OS or distribution. What OS are you using?

Comment: I have enterprise linux server release 5.8

Comment: I have enterprise linux server release 5.8 Now I downloaded the .rpm for Linux 5. When I try to install, it is saying file /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ruby-shadow-2.4.1/shadow.0 from install of chef-12.0.1-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package chef-12.01-1.x86_64. The old install has been deleted & the is no chef under /opt

Comment: The package you mentioned is the Chef omnibus installer, not ChefDK. Which are you trying to install?

Comment: I removed both chef & chefdk by rpm -qa *chef* and yum remove <pacakge> I now installed the right version 5 for enterprise linux, and chef client is running fine. But I see chefdk only for Linux 6, will this chefdk work on Linux 5.8

Comment: That is correct, ChefDK does not have packages for RHEL5.

Answer (score 0):

use yum install ruby
you are getting errors because ruby is not installed

Answer (score -1):

You have to install the omnibus dependency for the particular flavor of OS , then only the `GLIB_C` , dependency will resolve . So please install from the below link. [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/archives/)